# How to check if two strings length are equal in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in c# and unity and Wondering how could I write this code to check if two string lengths are equal.

with this code unity system shows this error:
error CS1061: Type `char' does not contain a definition for`Length' and no extension method `Length' of type`char' could be found.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Answers.Length; i++) 
{
    if (GetAnswer[i].Length == Answers[i].Length) 
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Answers` is a string, then `Answers[i]` is a `char`.  Get rid of the `[i]` part.  I'm assuming that `GetAnswer` is an array.  (by the way, that's why it's a good idea to show more information, so we don't have to guess these things).  Note that @SirRufo and I are saying the same thing, but we're guessing your types backwards to each other

Comment: GetAnswer seems to be of type `string` and `GetAnswer[i]` is the i th char of GetAnswer string. I guess you want to compare `GetAnswer.Length == Answers[i].Length`

Comment: Please let us know the type of `Answers` and `GetAnswer`.

Comment: There is a question like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057956/comparing-string-lengths-in-c-sharp

Comment: To compare the lengths, you can just do `if ("someString".Length == "otherString".Length)`. You seem to be treating them as an array for some reason...

Comment: can you post more code specifying the data type for answers and GetAnswer

Answer (score 1):

```
if (yourString.Length == yourOtherString.Length)
{
 //dosomething
}
```

should check if a string is equals in length to another
The problem with your code is that a string is an array of char so it calculate the length of the char (Which do not exist)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Answers.Length+1; i++) 
{
    if (GetAnswer.Length == Answers.Length) 
    {
    //Do something
    }
}
```

You also need to increment the value of the for to get the  correct length otherwise the Answers.Length will always be short of 1